# Redirect node/id to node/path-auto-alias

Tags: 8, redirection, path-aliases

**Using Drupal 8**

I need to set various links between my content types and so far I'm setting the link using their **path-auto-generated-alias**, but that's terrible practice because if I change the pattern one day I will have to change every single existance of the out of date url alias.

I've seen plenty of answers for **Drupal 7** with module [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) but it states that it's *deprecated* for Drupal 8 and to use [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) instead. I installed the module and I'm presented with this:

[image]

I have no idea what's amitted in there, tokens? If someone could direct me to a documentation where I can learn to use the module I'd really appreciate it since I'm at a loss.

The reason why I'm in that part is because I have the following Global Settings and it's not redirecting `/node/id` to expected Path Auto URL alias.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Found my mistake, you can't have `Check access to the redirected page` enabled in the global REDIRECTS.

[image]

Comment: if your nodes are published and accessible then it should still work with the access check. I also don't fully get what you're doing with links. Drupal should be able to generate the correct link  in most cases, be it an entity reference field, a link field. This should only come in to play if someone manually goes to node/1, links on the page should use the correct alias, as you otherwise have a redirect which makes it slower. If you have links inside body fields, have a look at pathologic, that might help.

Comment: I wanted to have the Global Redirects because sometimes (not always) in the body of my nodes I like to link to other nodes, and when inserting that link in the body I use the target node's PathAuto generated URL. Toady I realized that if I were to change that target node's URL Pattern in PathAuto ( say instead of /story/this-is-it to story/funny/this-is-it ) then I'd have to manually change the link I used in the body. But if I place the link with node/id then thanks to Global Redirect, I won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Yes, you can either use pathologic, which will display the correct alias already and if you are using redirect and pathauto, then redirect will also automatically register a redirect for the old alias anyway.

Comment: I am using Redirect to display the alias if it exists, but it won't work unless I  uncheck the "Check access to the redirected page" for some reason.