# How do I avoid mydomain.com/node/1 or mydomain.com/node/4 is used?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I am using the Pathauto module for creating user-friendly and SEO-friendly URLs. 
Therefore, I do not want and there is no need that the "old URL" like mydomain.com/node/1 or mydomain.com/node/4 is any longer public. So, how do I hide this and make only the path aliases public?

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220260/redirect-node-id-to-node-path-auto-alias

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/redirect

Answer (score 0):

You need to create patterns for pathauto and go back to those nodes and save them, ensuring “generate new alias” is checked off on the node form.

Comment: I have done this, but nevertheless you can still use .../node/1 and .../node/2 and .../node/3 and so on

Comment: Those are system paths, you cannot block that out. It should redirect to the path alias.

Comment: I do that with the redirect module and get the answer "You are attempting to redirect the page to itself. This will result in an infinite loop."

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the Redirect Module. It comes with three modules. I enable the Redirect Module and the Redirect Domain Module. Then I create in tab Domain Redirect a redirect from subdomain /node/* to front-page (using alias of front-page). It works and this solution is ok for me.