# Deactivate system path

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

I want to deactivate the system path which comes with Drupal.
I've installed the pathauto, so when I create a new page, it automatically changes **domain.com/node/12** to **domain.com/books/jacks-journey**

But both page exist. I only want the **/books/jacks-journey** to exist and deactive the **/node/12**. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Define "deactivate". Do you want to return a 404 response? What Drupal version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect node/id to node/path-auto-alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220260/redirect-node-id-to-node-path-auto-alias)

Answer (score 3):

Deactivating the internal path is technically route normalization by redirecting incoming requests, which in D8 is provided by the module Redirect:

> D8: Maintaining a canonical path and redirecting alternative URL's
>   like non-aliased path, path without language prefixes and so on
>   (Previously provided by Global redirect)

https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect